# C++ undeclared identifier &syntax error & cannot delete objects that are not pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to make a student review system and there are those bugs I could not debug. Here is the .h and .cpp file codes.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class StudentReviewSystem
{
    public:
    StudentReviewSystem();
    ~StudentReviewSystem();

    void addCourse(const int courseId,const string courseName);
    void deleteCourse(const int courseId);
    void addStudent(const int courseId, const int studentId, const string studentName);
    void dropStudent(const int courseId, const int studentId);
    void addGradeForm(const int courseId, const int formId, const double weight);
    void deleteGradeForm(const int courseId, const int formId);
    void showAllCourses();
    void showCourse(const int courseId);
    void showStudent(const int studentId);

    int studentArraySize;
    int courseArraySize;
    Student *studentArray;
    Course *courseArray;
};
```

The errors I have are :

```
>c:\users\kaan mert berkem\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project2\project2\studentreviewsystem.h(22): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\kaan mert berkem\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project2\project2\studentreviewsystem.h(22): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\kaan mert berkem\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project2\project2\studentreviewsystem.h(23): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\kaan mert berkem\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\project2\project2\studentreviewsystem.h(23): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

This is the constructor and one the functions of my srs system. In this part I constantly get error that are :
courseArray undeclared identifier, 
delete : cannot delete objects that are not pointers,
left of '.getId' must have class/struct/union

```
#include "StudentReviewSystem.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

//constructor
StudentReviewSystem::StudentReviewSystem() {
    int studentArraySize = 0;
    int courseArraySize = 0;

Student *studentArray = new Student[studentArraySize];
Course *courseArray = new Course[courseArraySize];
}

//functions
void StudentReviewSystem::deleteCourse(const int cId) {
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < courseArraySize; i++) {
    if (courseArray[i].getId() == cId) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    cout << "Course " << cId << "is not found" << endl;
}
else {
    for (int i = 0; i < courseArraySize; i++) {
        if (courseArray[i].getId() == cId) {
            cout << "Course " << courseArray[i].getId() << " has been deleted" << endl;
            courseArray[i].~Course();
        }
    }

    Course *cArr = new Course[courseArraySize - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < courseArraySize - 2 && &courseArray[i]!= NULL; i++) {
         cArr[i] = courseArray[i]; 
    }

    for (int i = courseArraySize - 2; i > 0 && &courseArray[i] != NULL; i--) {
        cArr[i] = courseArray[i + 1];
    }

    delete []courseArray;
    courseArray = new Course[courseArraySize - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < courseArraySize; i++) {
        courseArray[i] = cArr[i];
    }
    delete []cArr;
}
}
```

What do I have to fix those errors?

Comment: You're defining plain pointers and deal as arrays of pointers with them. That won't work of course.

Comment: can you be more specific? where is he deailing as arrays of pointers with them?

Comment: @FredrickGauss seen the `new[]` and `delete[]` usage?

Comment: @g-makulik, there is nothing array of pointers in this question. And there is no error about `new[]` and `delete[]` usage there. But there is subtle mistake that is redeclaring `studentArray` and `courseArray` arrays in the constructor and this is not related to your claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included the headers for `Student` and `Course`, e.g.

```
#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"
```

or forward declared them,

```
class Student;
class Course;
```

?

The error

> missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

usually signifies that the compiler has not yet seen the return type of a function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In the `StudentReviewSystem` class you are using the `Student` and `Course` classes, but you haven't declared them. Simply declare them before the `StudentReviewSystem` class:

```
class Student;
class Course;

class StudentReviewSystem
{
    ...
};
```

---

You also have some other problems, like in the constructor you declare `studentArray` and `courseArray` as local variables, and not using the member variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should  either include headers where types Student and Course are declared or substitute these lines

```
Student *studentArray;
Course *courseArray;
```

};

for

```
class Student *studentArray;
class Course *courseArray;
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by declaring the necessity of another head file only if it was necessary   and when one file above calls file below , you must not call the file that is over and the other , is enough to call the one that is above them.